# Best way to generate a random color in javascript?

Tags: javascript, random

What is the best way to generate a random color in JavaScript Without using any frameworks...

Here are a couple of solutions I came up with:

```
function get_random_color() 
{
    var color = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        var sub = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256).toString(16);
        color += (sub.length == 1 ? "0" + sub : sub);
    }
    return "#" + color;
}

function get_rand_color()
{
    var color = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.pow(256, 3)).toString(16);
    while(color.length < 6) {
        color = "0" + color;
    }
    return "#" + color;
}
```

Are there better ways to do it?

Comment: If you're generating colors for humans and need a large number of distinguishable colors you may be better off with random HSV (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) values.  Because you can provide fewer possibilities for S and V but still get colors that look different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Random color generator in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484506/random-color-generator-in-javascript)

Answer (score 135):

A shorter way:

```
'#'+(0x1000000+Math.random()*0xffffff).toString(16).substr(1,6)
```

Comment: Very short solution indeed =) I would give you +1 but I can see this failing in the (admittedly very rare) cases that `Math.random` returns values like `0.0` or `0.5`.

Comment: true, now it should be ok (and quite close your solution but shorter :)

Comment: Yup, but now you've got the problem with having to pad the string with 0 (if result is `<= 0xFFFFF`) That's what I'm doing in the second statement.

Comment: +1: Using the same style (i.e. space between operators etc.), your code is somewhere around 35 characters shorter =) Here's the formatted version of your code I used for comparison: `return '#' + (0x1000000 + Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF).toString(16).substr(1,6);`

Comment: Soubok, would you mind me using your solution over at javascriptcookbook.com? A reader thought it would be a nice addition.

Comment: If you intend to generate obscene amounts of random colors (millions), flooring the number is up to an order of magnitude faster (because `toString` has to work much less with an integer): `'#' + (0x1000000 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 0x1000000)).toString(16).substr(1);` (note that the multiplication must be with `0x1000000` instead of `0xFFFFFF` because `Math.random` returns range `[0, 1)` – that is, it will never return `1.0`). https://jsperf.com/random-hex-color

Comment: redundant parentheses around `(Math.random())`

Comment: Thanks for the the answer. Since `substr` is deprecated, it will be great to replace it with `substring`. But note that the with `substring.

Answer (score 16):

Here's a way to generate a random color and provide the minimum brightness:

```
function randomColor(brightness){
  function randomChannel(brightness){
    var r = 255-brightness;
    var n = 0|((Math.random() * r) + brightness);
    var s = n.toString(16);
    return (s.length==1) ? '0'+s : s;
  }
  return '#' + randomChannel(brightness) + randomChannel(brightness) + randomChannel(brightness);
}
```

Call randomColor with a value from 0-255, indicitating how bright the color should be. This is helpful for generating pastels, for example `randomColor(220)`

Comment: This is the best code I have seen so far that works based on HSV.. Great work.. Use it if you want random light colors in your page.. Here is some further reading http://martin.ankerl.com/2009/12/09/how-to-create-random-colors-programmatically/

Answer (score 14):

I like your second option, although it can be made a little bit simpler:

```
// Math.pow is slow, use constant instead.
var color = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777216).toString(16);
// Avoid loops.
return '#000000'.slice(0, -color.length) + color;
```

Comment: I don't think `substr` is deprecated, but it's less standard than `substring` and `slice`. It's worth noting that `substr` behaves differently from `substring` too. Anyways, I changed to `slice` because it makes the code simpler as an extra bonus. =)

Comment: Or on one line: 
```"#" + ("000000" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777216).toString(16)).substr(-6);```

Answer (score 12):

I did it like this, with the help of other answers:

```
'#' + parseInt(Math.random() * 0xffffff).toString(16)
```

Comment: `0.06029829654625929 => #f6fb5`,
`0.01086451193560456 => #2c804`,
`0.013915316490329177 => #38ff4`,
`0.0421506948772119 => #aca63`,
`0.0067180071741699265 => #1b845`,
`0.02415522842446105 => #62f09`,
`0.01397159804923187 => #393a4`,
`0.01909063159540958 => #4e31f`

Comment: #333 is the same colour as #333333 - this isn't trully random

Answer (score 9):

As George said the best way is to use HSL, so you can generate a bunch of random human-distinguishable colours. The similar idea is implemented in [Adams Cole answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7419630/421010) to the similar question, but his code have random color generator and hsl->hex rgb translator bundled together which makes it hard to understand and modify.

If you use one of the javascript color manipulation libraries (like [jquery-color](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color/)) color generation become trivial:

```
function rainbow() {
  // 30 random hues with step of 12 degrees
  var hue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30) * 12;

  return $.Color({
    hue: hue,
    saturation: 0.9,
    lightness: 0.6,
    alpha: 1
  }).toHexString();
};
```

Comment: Is it possible to "add" another color and essentially have it pick up where it left off? For example, say you start with 30 items to color, but the user adds a 31st item. Is there a way to have it continue with its currently generated set and simply generate a 31st color that adheres to the prior hues and steps?

Answer (score 6):

More succinct:

```
function get_random_color2() 
{
    var r = function () { return Math.floor(Math.random()*256) };
    return "rgb(" + r() + "," + r() + "," + r() + ")";
}
```

Comment: You should define the function outside the `get_random_color2` function... Redefining a function for every call feels a bit unnecessary. The solution that was linked earlier was better, because it only called `Math.random` once, then used bit shifting to get the red/green/blue components.

Comment: @Blixt here is what you talked about:
`function randomRGB(){
  var c = Math.random()*16777215;
  return 'rgb('+((c >> 16) & 0xff)+','+((c >> 8) & 0xff)+','+(c & 0xff)+')';
}`

Answer (score 4):

```
function randomColor()
{
     color='rgb('+Math.round(Math.random()*255)+','+Math.round(Math.random()*255)+','+Math.round(Math.random()*255)+')';

     return color;
}
```

This returns a random RGB value.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is the best method.

You should provide known colors to choose from instead of relying on purely numeric methods. You can use sites like [ColorBrewer](http://colorbrewer2.org/) to choose color palettes that work well depending on the problem (qualitative dataset, quantitative, or whatever..)

`['red','orange','yellow','green','blue','purple'][Math.random()*6|0]`

```js
var colors = {
  rainbow: ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'purple'],
  qual: ['#8dd3c7', '#ffffb3', '#bebada', '#fb8072', '#80b1d3', '#fdb462', '#b3de69', '#fccde5', '#d9d9d9', '#bc80bd', '#ccebc5', '#ffed6f'],
  quant: ['#fff7ec', '#fee8c8', '#fdd49e', '#fdbb84', '#fc8d59', '#ef6548', '#d7301f', '#b30000', '#7f0000'],
  div: ['#67001f','#b2182b','#d6604d','#f4a582','#fddbc7','#f7f7f7','#d1e5f0','#92c5de','#4393c3','#2166ac','#053061']
};
randc = function(array) {
  return array[Math.random() * array.length | 0]
}
genc = function() {
  var frag = [];
  var arr = colors[$("select").val()];
  for (var i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
    frag.push("<div style='background-color:" + randc(arr) + ";'></div>");
  }
  $("#demo").html(frag.join(''));
}
genc();
$("select").on("change", genc);
```

```css
#demo {
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 0;
}
#demo div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value='qual'>Qualitative (categorical)</option>
  <option value='quant'>Quantitative (sequential)</option>
  <option value='div'>Divergent (republicans versus democrats)</option>
  <option value='rainbow'>Rainbow (my little pony)</option>
</select>
<div id='demo'></div>
```

Comment: Please update with why this answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Most succinct:

```
function get_random_color()
{
  return '#' + Math.random().toString(16).substring(4);
}
```

[Nicolas Buduroi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179316/nicolas-buduroi) gave the above best code to get random color at [Random Color generator in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484506/random-color-generator-in-javascript)

Comment: This will return invalid colors often, the amount of decimal places Math.random() returns varies greatly. in FF it returns strings longer than 6 digits, and chrome/safari can go as low as 2 digits

Answer (score 1):

I have created a slightly more complicated solution but one which lets you control the saturation of the colors and the brightness. You can check out the code for SwitchColors.js here https://github.com/akulmehta/SwitchColors.js