# How do I randomly generate HTML hex color codes using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Random Color generator in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484506/random-color-generator-in-javascript)

I have some data I'd like to display in different colors and I want to generate the colors randomly if possible.  How can I generate the Hex Color Code using JavaScript?

Answer (score 223, accepted):

This will generate a random number within the bounds and convert it to hexadecimal. It is then padded with zeros so that it's always a valid six-digit hex code.

```js
'#'+(Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF << 0).toString(16).padStart(6, '0');
```

Comment: note that this method outputs wrong color codes, too: `> '#'+(.001*0xffffff<<0).toString(16) ---> '#4189'`

Comment: I don't prefer shorthand ways. A boring longhand way would be a lot clearer about what is going on. If I saw this code by itself, it would take me a long time to connect it with its express purpose.

Comment: I used then it shows some error at some point. please use the accepted answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484506/random-color-generator

Comment: Like @Scheintod said, this occasionally produces wrong values. I just got `#c5935`

Comment: @adjenks your edit is a completely different answer. You should post it as its own answer, not an edit that removes all of someone else's code.

Comment: @camille I suppose, but.. It's gone now... Oh well...

Comment: Also, I cannot add an answer here because it's locked. I liked the solution but I wanted to fix the problem that Scheintod pointed out. I edited again, but a bit less radically.

Comment: @MarredCheese Really? I can't make the code less buggy? I think that my edit does actually "strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner."

Comment: Where can we find the explanation of your code? Can you give details/explanation why ` * 0xFFFFFF << 0` to get a hex value?

Answer (score 109):

There are a variety of methods in the blog post [Random hex color code generator in JavaScript](http://paulirish.com/2009/random-hex-color-code-snippets/).  You need to pad with zeros when the random value is less than `0×100000`, so here's the correct version:

```
var randomColor = "#000000".replace(/0/g,function(){return (~~(Math.random()*16)).toString(16);});
```

That replaces each of six `0`s with a random hex digit, so it's sure to end up with a full six-digit valid color value.

Comment: This is the one that generated valid HTML codes all the time

Comment: First time I'm seeing use of squigly line "~" 