# How do I make part of a style element a function? (IE: color:$random instead of color:red)

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is probably a really noob question, but I couldn't figure out on my own thus far.. The title pretty much covers it up but I'm looking for how I can change the element some CSS into a function, in this case random.

To rephrase and provide more of a picture for you I want the program I am working on to look like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<p onClick="document.Color='$randomColor'"> Test sentence. </p>
</body>
</html>
```

as opposed to what I have now.

```
<html>
<body>
<p onClick="document.Color='green'"> Test sentence. </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone please help me? Many thanks in advance if anyone can!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function getRandomColor()
{
var r = Math.floor(Math.random()*256);
var g = Math.floor(Math.random()*256);
var b = Math.floor(Math.random()*256);
return r.toString(16)+g.toString(16)+b.toString(16);
}
</script>
</head>
<body id="bd">
<p onclick="document.getElementById('bd').style.color='#'+getRandomColor();"> Test sentence. </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Already got it now, but this is pretty much exactly what I'm doing, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use javascript's Math.random() function. Look it up to see how it works.

EDIT: What I mean is, get 3 random numbers between 0 and 255 inclusive (make sure they are integers and not floating point numbers!) and then set each of the R, G, and B values of the background to one of the 3 random numbers.

Comment: I'm well aware of javascript's Math.random() function, saying that doesn't help much. I was asking how I could do the above. I guess what you're saying is it's the exact format I have above but I need to insert javascript randomly generating hexadecimal values for it and then it will work fine. So.. I guess I figured it out in that case.. Thanks?

Answer (score 0):

To generate a random color just do:

```
'#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
```

From original post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5092846/1174076

Answer (score -1):

you can use jQuery

```
$("p"),click(function(){
    $(this).css("color", randomColor);
});
```