# How to translate javascript code to bash for random hex colors

Tags: javascript, bash

I just found a great answer to generate random valid hex code colors [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092808/how-do-I-randomly-generate-html-hex-color-codes-using-javascript):

```
var randomColor = "#000000".replace(/0/g,function(){return (~~(Math.random()*16)).toString(16);});
```

and I would like to translate that to bash, I'm still scratching my head to do so. I appreciate if you can shed some lights to achieve this.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: it's just a simple question, but no problem, I will delete it, thanks anyway

Comment: I just undeleted it because of Jaime, thanks dude!!

Comment: Btw, you can downvote or close my post if you want it and feel it @Frederic and the other 4 guys, I just don't care about votes, it's about learning IMHO =)

Comment: You may have a hard time learning since the answer does not contain any explanation whatsoever, but if that suits you, fine. However, I find quite odd that the automatically generated comment with my custom close reason was removed -- it was not rude or offensive, and moderators are not supposed to remove close reason comments. Bah, it's not like I will lose sleep over this anyway.

Comment: I didn't delete that if you ask me, so good sleep 8-), and Jaime's answer is pretty easy to understand, so he provided a constructive idea and solution, so he's part of the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-f0-9' | fold -w 6 | head -n 1`

Comment: @Jaime thanks for that useful answer, just one question, is there a way to get unique values? I mean, with `for i in `seq 1 1000`; do cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-f0-9' | fold -w 6 | head -n 1; done` I get 1000 different codes?, thanks again!

Comment: simply with `cat uniques | sort | uniq` just found they are "uniq", so it really works, thanks again @Jaime!

Comment: you can use `head -c6` insteed of `fold -w 6 | head -n 1` .