# Changing color randomly Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, random, colors

Heys guys,

I am testing some stuff out with the native accelometer on my android phone, I want to draw rectangles, which works but I want them to be a different color everytime one is drawn.

Thank you in advance :)

```
    function onSuccess(acceleration) {

var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.width = window.innerWidth;
context.height = window.innerHeight;

    context.save(); 
    context.beginPath();
    context.rect(acceleration.x*10+150, acceleration.y*10+100, acceleration.z*10, acceleration.y*10);
    context.fillStyle = '#FF0000';
    context.fill();
    context.lineWidth = 3;
    context.strokeStyle = 'black';
    context.stroke();
    context.restore(); 

}

function onError() {
    alert('onError!');
}
```

Comment: `fillStyle` should have `random` color..

Comment: You can use any of these Paul Irish's codes: http://www.paulirish.com/2009/random-hex-color-code-snippets/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fillStyle` should have random color instead of `'#FF0000'`

You can use [`random` color](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/random-hex-color-code-snippets/) by [**Paul Irish**](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/random-hex-color-code-snippets/)

```js
function onSuccess(acceleration) {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  context.width = window.innerWidth;
  context.height = window.innerHeight;
  context.save();
  context.beginPath();
  context.rect(acceleration.x * 10 + 150, acceleration.y * 10 + 100, acceleration.z * 10, acceleration.y * 10);
  context.fillStyle = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
  context.fill();
  context.lineWidth = 3;
  context.strokeStyle = 'black';
  context.stroke();
  context.restore();
}

function onError() {
  alert('onError!');
}
```

**Edit:** As suggested by [*Morten Olsen*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1689055/morten-olsen), provided approach may fail sometimes, You can refer this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092808/how-do-i-randomly-generate-html-hex-color-codes-using-javascript)

Comment: There is a chance in the above that it would give fever charactors, for instance `'#' + Math.floor(23421).toString(16)` would be `'#5b7d'`, not a valid hex color

Comment: What will be the value of `Math.random()` to produce such result ?

Comment: Math.floor(0.06 * 16777215).toString(16) as an example would result in #f5c28

Answer (score 0):

Just take a function for it.

```js
function randomColor() {
   var c = "#";
   for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
       c += (Math.random() * 16 | 0).toString(16);
   } 
   return c;
}

var a = document.getElementById("id1").style;
a.color = randomColor();
```

```html
<h1 id="id1">stackoverflow</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign a random color to fillStyle.

```
 context.fillStyle = "#"+((1<<24)*Math.random()|0).toString(16);
```

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484506/random-color-generator-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
'#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
```

For more information: http://www.paulirish.com/2009/random-hex-color-code-snippets/