# Can I add strings in one array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, sorting

I want to create a random color-picker with javascript and for that, I want random hex codes. The part with getting the hex codes is done but they appear as strings on different lines when I use console.log(); and not as one string on one line. [image]

Does someone know how to change it? I already tried to set it as an array but it still appears on different lines because I used a for-loop and I can't change the name of the different strings because of that. Sorry for my poor explanation but here is the code for you to run it and maybe help me out:

```js
let hexDigits = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F",
  "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"
];

for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  let hexColor = hexDigits[Math.floor(Math.random() * hexDigits.length)];

  console.log(hexColor);
}
```

Comment: Why do you re-invent the wheel? Here use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092808/how-do-i-randomly-generate-html-hex-color-codes-using-javascript

Comment: @NinoFiliu The Q&A you refer to as a duplicate is itself a duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store to a string and append to it, printing only when you're done.

```js
let hexDigits = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F",
  "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"
];

let hexColor = "";

for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  hexColor += hexDigits[Math.floor(Math.random() * hexDigits.length)];
}

console.log("#" + hexColor);
```

Comment: Thank you! I just started learning javascript and I sat there for an hour and tried everything and the result was that close :D