# Random Color Generator with Hue/Saturation and more controls

Tags: javascript

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484506/random-color-generator-in-javascript) I found a lot of interesting functions to generate random colors.

I need a random color generator that accept ***Hue***, ***Saturation*** and ***Darkness*** range and also number of colors that we need.

Actually I can write a random color generator but I don't have good understanding of relationship between color numbers and *darkness*, *hue* and *saturation* of a color. I want the function export colors in an array.

I also made a [jsfiddle file here](http://jsfiddle.net/5V8mV/) for testing:

```
function get_random_color() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
    }
    return color;
}
$.each($('div'),function(){
    $(this).css('background-color', get_random_color());
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In CSS3 capable browsers, there's no need to transform HSL colors to RGB, since you can assign them just like that:

```
function rand(min, max) {
    return min + Math.random() * (max - min);
}

function get_random_color() {
    var h = rand(1, 360);
    var s = rand(0, 100);
    var l = rand(0, 100);
    return 'hsl(' + h + ',' + s + '%,' + l + '%)';
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5V8mV/1/

With that algorithm, you can easily restrict the colors to bluish tones for example:
http://jsfiddle.net/DH2Bk/

In case you need an RGB conversion algorithm (for IE8, for example), you'll find it directly in the specs: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#hsl-color

> ```
> HOW TO RETURN hsl.to.rgb(h, s, l):
>    SELECT:
>      l<=0.5: PUT l*(s+1) IN m2
>      ELSE: PUT l+s-l*s IN m2
>    PUT l*2-m2 IN m1
>    PUT hue.to.rgb(m1, m2, h+1/3) IN r
>    PUT hue.to.rgb(m1, m2, h    ) IN g
>    PUT hue.to.rgb(m1, m2, h-1/3) IN b
>    RETURN (r, g, b)
>
> HOW TO RETURN hue.to.rgb(m1, m2, h): 
>    IF h<0: PUT h+1 IN h
>    IF h>1: PUT h-1 IN h
>    IF h*6<1: RETURN m1+(m2-m1)*h*6
>    IF h*2<1: RETURN m2
>    IF h*3<2: RETURN m1+(m2-m1)*(2/3-h)*6
>    RETURN m1
> ```

---

#### Edit:

I just found a nice JS library with more options on https://github.com/davidmerfield/randomColor

Comment: Thank you very much! That was great idea. HSL is the best color system I've seen. I've made something based on your help here: http://jsfiddle.net/NzTUB/ Please check it out and tell me why Hue do not work properly? I think the rand function is not good enough for hue while hue accept values more than 100.

Comment: You need to make sure that the input field's values are passed as Numbers, not as strings - otherwise my `rand()` function messes up. Or replace it by `function rand(min, max) {
    min = parseFloat(min);
    max = parseFloat(max);
    return parseInt(Math.random() * (max-min+1), 10) + min;
}`