# How to generate light colour shades in javascript

Tags: javascript

Hello all I am working in JavaScript and want to generate colors for my graph.And I want a new color for every line and also the color should be light in shade.

I have read about question of color generation in java script

[Random color generator in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484506/random-color-generator-in-javascript)

As I want new color for my line so random number generation will not work in my case
Also the color should be light

I have read about the colors RGB values but I didn't find them following any pattern as how to choose light color

So any one can please guide me as is there a way to generate colors in sequence (avoid random) and choose only light color or any other function to make dark color lighter

Thanks

http://cloford.com/resources/colours/500col.htm

Comment: You should use HSL color (google for it) in order to be able to define easily light or dark colors. It's [available in HTML5](https://www.google.com/?q=html5+hsl).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try this way:

```
var new_light_color = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor((256-229)*Math.random()) + 230) + ',' + 
                                    (Math.floor((256-229)*Math.random()) + 230) + ',' + 
                                    (Math.floor((256-229)*Math.random()) + 230) + ')';
```

This way you generate colors that have red, green and blue in the range 230 - 256, which is a light color. You can go lower by changing the numbers, for darker colors.

Comment: @A_user depending on the browser you have to support you could use a color space different from `rgb`: `hsl` it has an extra channel "lightness". more info: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#hsl-color It's supported in all major browsers and IE9

Comment: Well, hsl and hsla can be generated randomly similar to what I said above.