# jquery cycle - add then remove css class - infinite loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, cycle, infinite

How do I use jQuery to infinitely add then remove a CSS class on a set of 4 li's.

Basically, see this simple fiddle (without any jquery): http://jsfiddle.net/kHsvN/

I want to cycle through the boxes to change the css of a box, flip back to original css, then go on to the next one etc etc...

Any help appreciated!

Comment: As far as I understand this, at any given time there should be one box having the class?

Comment: @Ben Davis, Check my updated answer/fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   window.setInterval(function() {
        $("#topboxesmenu li a").each(function() {
            $(this).css("background", get_random_color());
    });
  }, 1000);
});

function get_random_color() {
   var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
   var color = '#';
   for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
     color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
   }
   return color;
}
```

This example uses a random colour, but could easily be changed to `.addClass()` in the `.each` part.

**JS Fiddle (Live Example)**

http://jsfiddle.net/kHsvN/6/

[Random color generator in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484506/random-color-generator-in-javascript)

Comment: Impressive but perhaps overly-complex for the OP's requirement :)

Answer (score 1):

You may try this

**CSS** For current item, class to be added/removed

```
ul#topboxesmenu li a.current{ background:black }
```

**JS**

```
$('#topboxesmenu li a').each(function(i){
    var t=$(this);
    setTimeout(function(){
        t.addClass('current');
        setTimeout(function(){
            t.removeClass('current');
        }, 1000);
    }, 1100*i);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kHsvN/11/)

**Update:** For continuous loop

```
$(function(){
    loopIt();
});

function loopIt(){    
    $('#topboxesmenu li a').each(function(i){
        var t=$(this);
        setTimeout(function(){
            t.addClass('current');
                setTimeout(function(){
                    t.removeClass('current');
                    if(i==$('#topboxesmenu li a').length-1) loopIt();;
                }, 1000);
        }, 1100*i);
    });
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kHsvN/13/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    window.setInterval(function() {
            var oldBox = jQuery('#topboxesmenu li.active');
            if(oldBox.length == 0 || oldBox.next().length == 0)
            {
                    oldBox.removeClass('active');
                jQuery('#topboxesmenu li:first-child').addClass('active');
            }
            else
                oldBox.removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
    },2000);
});
```

It will cycle through the boxes, adding an active class to them one after the other.

http://jsfiddle.net/gKEmL/

Comment: No still no joy :( Don't understand as it works fine in jfiddle http://www.deeside.ac.uk/build/test.php

Comment: There seems to be some invisible character at the end of the script that is illegal, probably a non breaking space from copy&paste. Try to copy&paste the code from jsfiddle instead from here maybe.

Comment: Or as an alternative delete anything between the }); and </script> as well as <script...> and jQuery(doc

Comment: Thanks, tidied the code up and still not working unfortunately :( http://www.deeside.ac.uk/build/test.php

Comment: I just don't know where the characters come in... try to copy&paste from here: http://pastebin.com/ChXmg0Fc

Comment: Bardiir - a little more help if you will. I've update the test page, what I am after is the boxes to show their hover state background, one after the other, in an infinite loop, is this possible? http://www.deeside.ac.uk/build/test.php    thanks

Comment: Just replace the CSS selectors: `ul#topboxesmenu li a.schoolleavers:hover` -> `ul#topboxesmenu li a.schoolleavers:hover, ul#topboxesmenu li.active a.schoolleavers` and likewise for all the other hovers... this way the hover state will react to hover and to the active class.

Comment: You have saved me sooo much headache and time! Works magnificently. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think this is doing what you want:

```
el = $('#topboxesmenu li:first-child');
setInterval(function() {
    el = window.el;
    el.siblings().children('a').css('background','#ff0000');
    el.children('a').css('background-color', 'blue');
    el = el.next().length ? el.next() : el.parent().children('li:first-child');
}, 1000);​
```

See [**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yxEzM/)

**UPDATE**:
Regarding your test page don't working, you have your javascript outside the body tag, try putting your `</body>` tag just before the `</html>` tag. You currently have this:

```
</body>

<script type="text/javascript" ....
...
...
</html>
```

**UPDATE 2**:
Also your jquery script tag :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
```

should be placed inside the `<head>` of your page, not the body where you currently have it.

Comment: Thanks Nelson, trying your solution on a different test page and it's not working either :S http://www.deeside.ac.uk/build/test2.php

Comment: I spotted another wrong thing, your jquery library should be place inside <head>, see my updated answer.