# Automatic Hex rgb colour generation

Tags: javascript, hex, rgba

I am generating heatmap style colours in JavaScript based on the values from cold to hot. But for some reason I am getting some pinks and some purples.

There are lots of answers on stackoverflow but they mostly relate to generating using HSL, and unfortunately for Google Earth I need RGBA format (backwards as ABGR)

1 = red = hot

0.5 = green = middle

0 = blue = cold

```
    function generateColor(value) {
        var r = Math.round(value * 255),
            g = Math.round((1 - Math.abs(0.5 - value)) * 255),
            b = Math.round((1 - value) * 255);
        r = r.toString(16);
        g = g.toString(16);
        b = b.toString(16);
        if (r.length < 2) {
            r += r;
        }
        if (g.length < 2) {
            g += g;
        }
        if (b.length < 2) {
            b += b;
        }
        return 'ff' + b + g + r;
    }
```

There's a bug in here somewhere!! Here's a fiddle I've been using to try and work out the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/kmturley/sT8BL/1/

Comment: Are you sure it's ABGR and not ARGB?

Comment: for Google Earth it's aabbggrr :( https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/geometries#linestring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is here:

```
if (r.length < 2) {
    r += r;
}
```

If `r` is just one character, add a `0`, not itself to it:

```
if (r.length < 2) {
    r = "0" + r;
}
```

In just one line:

```
r = ("0" + r.toString(16)).slice(-2);
```

But you can also put most of the function in just a line:

```
function generateColor(value) {
    var r = Math.round(value * 255),
        g = Math.round((1 - Math.abs(0.5 - value)) * 255),
        b = Math.round((1 - value) * 255);
    return (0xff000000 + 0x10000 * b + 256 * g + r).toString(16);
}
```

Comment: nice this works much better! however the colours are a little off: http://jsfiddle.net/kmturley/sT8BL/2/

Comment: @KimT I see... I guess it may be because you chose green as the intermediate color, while yellow could have been a better choice. But to do so you have to modify the way you compute `r`, `g` and `b`... which will make you wonder if HSL isn't better. You can still convert the values to RGB, you know.

Comment: yeah maybe I do that, the HSL to RGB function is a little bit hefty http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353211/hsl-to-rgb-color-conversion

Comment: @KimT Cool, I posted a [more compact](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17338858/714240) version some months ago, if you want to give it a try.