# jQuery, CSS: auto-color HTML lists?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-lists

**How to generate different background colors for list elements automatically?**

Here is the static `html` code what should be displayed with different background-color.

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href=#">I am the first element</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href=#">I am the 2nd element</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href=#">I am the 3rd element</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

No chance to add `class` or `style` manually, so I think using *jQuery* is the easiest solution. Here is my first try:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.toc > ul > li').each(function(e){
        var n = $(this).children().text().length*222222;
        var h = n.toString(16).substr(0,6);
        $(this).css({'background-color':'#'+h});
        //$(this).append(h);
    });
});
```

The result is a bit ugly, and there are similar colors what make this script unusable.

**Any other idea to make beautiful automatically colorized lists?**

Comment: `var n = $(this).children().text().length*222222;
        var h = n.toString(16).substr(0,6);` Is this supposed to be a random hex code generator?

Comment: Can you provide some information about how you would like them colored?  e.g., randomly, alternating, following some pattern (rainbow), etc.

Comment: not using random, because trying to use fixed colors, based on content.
following some pattern should be great, or using some predefined nice pantone-like colours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make thing look good you're going to need to define a set of colours. Random colours will often be awful.

```
var clr = "000000,22222,44444,66666,88888,a0a0a0".split(",")
$('.toc > ul > li').each(function(){
      $(this).css('background-color',clr[$(this).index()])   
})
```

Answer (score 0):

See this page:

[Random color generator in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484506/random-color-generator-in-javascript)

Also using it i have created a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/3exK5/

```
var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
var color = '#';
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
    color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
}
    $(this).css({'background-color':''+color+''});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for random colors that look sort of similar(?) you might want to look into using `hsl()` to define your colors.

You could just do like...

```
hsl( randomNumberBetween0and360, 100%, 50% );
```

and get a bunch of colors that looks like they belong with each other.

Here is a quick demo: http://jsbin.com/EKediJU/1/edit?html,js,output

If you need support for IE there's a nice little script called [TinyColor](http://bgrins.github.io/TinyColor/) that can help.