# Random Color Strings

Tags: javascript

First, this is not a duplicate of: [Generate random string/characters in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349404/generate-a-string-of-5-random-characters-in-javascript)

I specifically want a string to change to random colours starting on green. I am writing in JS

```
function changeColor()
{
  var change;
  for( var i=0; i < 11; i++ )
  {
    change += script.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() //Input ur suggestion here, I suspect it is the script variable and different colours
    script = document.getElementById('txt');
    script.style.color = "#33cc33";
  }
}
```

Comment: OK, and how about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484506/random-color-generator-in-javascript still not duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The for loop completes right away, you need a timeout to actually see the color change, and a random color generator to generate the colors, then throw in a recursive IIFE and you're there :

```
var color = '#33cc33',
    elem  = document.getElementById('txt');

(function fn() {
    elem.style.color = color;
    setTimeout(function() {
        color = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
        fn();
    }, 500);
})();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/4NBTA/1/)

Comment: Just curious, why did you multiply by 16777215?

Comment: It's the number of colors (minus 1), #FFFFFF converts to 16,777,215 in base ten, and we start at zero, so there are 16 777 216 colors available.

Comment: Also, when you declared the function why is there a parentheses before it? And is there a simpler way to use setTimeOut?

Comment: The parenthesis makes it execute without calling it, it's an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression). Not sure if there is a simpler way to use the timeout, but you could use an interval instead

Comment: Really sorry for the overload of questions, but I'm twelve so this is kinda hard to process. When you call the setTimeOut method, why do you  follow it with: (function() {. You never call that function. Again sorry, but what is the .toString(16) for

Comment: The function in setTimeout is an anonymous function, it's a common way to use a callback in setTimeout, [see this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp). The entire line with the `toString(16)` is a little complicated, but it creates the random color, and `toString(16)` simply converts the number we get from the math to a string with a base 16 (10 is decimal system etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Create an array with the valid hex color values:

```
var values = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', '0', '1', ... '9'];
```

Get a random value from that array:

```
var hex = values[Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length)];
```

...six times:

```
var hex = '#';
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
  hex += values[Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length)];
}
```

this can be made into a function:

```
function getRandomColor() {
    var values = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];
    var hex = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        hex += values[Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length)];
    }
    return hex;

}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v45gA/)