# How do that li tags changed their colors when I click my mouse on body field?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to click on the different fields on my website (in field body) and `<li>` tags should changed their colors. (random colors). How to do it?

```
<body onclick="highlight()">

<ul list style type = "none">
  <li id = "l0">this is line one</li>
  <li id = "l1">this is line two</li>
  <li id = "l2">this is line three</li>
</ul>

<script>
function highlight(name,color) {
  var a = document.getElementById(name);
  a.style.color = color;
}

highlight("l0", "red");
highlight("l2", "blue");

</script>

</body>
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484506/random-color-generator-in-javascript

Comment: put an `onclick` onto the li's to call your color changing function.

Comment: Help me. How to do it? I want to have random colors using Math.random.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first start with a click event for the body element

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
body.addEventListener('click', function(e) { highlight(); });
```

I've created a jsfiddle with a working solution. You should be able to modify it to fit your exact needs.

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/ewqre704/)

Answer (score 0):

For your random colors:

var colors = ['blue, 'red', 'green'];

var colorNumberIndex = Math.floor(color.length * Math.random()*1);

colors[colorNumberIndex];