# Selective random colors in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, colors

Given the following code to generate random colors ([credit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9513344/1712065)):

```
'#'+((1<<24)*(Math.random()+1)|0).toString(16).substr(1)
```

What conditions can be added to this code, in order to make it produce only bright colors but darker than pure white `#ffffff`.

The elements which are assigned these colors, need to be displayed on a dark background (`#111`).

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: What is your brightness threshold? You would basically try to determine if each pair of hex numbers are < ff and > some brightness threshold or 00.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than messing with the bitwise left-shift, it's probably easier to generate each digit separately, like so:

```
var color = '#';
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i+=1) {
  var first = Math.floor((Math.random()*8+8)).toString(16);
  var second = Math.floor((Math.random()*16)).toString(16);

  color = color + first + second;
}
```

If you want to adjust exactly how light/dark the colors are, change the `Math.random()*8+8` to adjust the first digit in each of the R, G, B values. As it stands, this will generate anything from #808080 to #ffffff. If you wanted from #a0a0a0 to #ffffff, change it `*10+6` - it can be anything in the form `*x+y` so long as `x` and `y` add up to 16.

Comment: Thank you! Not one-liner, but this code is more clear and readable. :)