# Change background-colour of div for each new div created

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a loop that creates a new div for each unique event

```
while($event!=$nextEvent){

echo'<div id='sportType'>';
//some code
echo'</div>'
}
```

I would like to automatically change the background-colour to a different background-colour for each created div, **each div must be a separate/unique colour, there will never be  more than 7 divs**

Something like this

[image]

Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: FYI, IDs must be unique on document context, you are generating invalid HTML markup

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since there is at most 7 divs, you can do this with pure css and the [nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) selector

```
div:nth-child(1) {
    background: gray;
}
div:nth-child(2) {
    background: red;
}
div:nth-child(3) {
    background: cyan;
}
div:nth-child(4) {
    background: blue;
}
div:nth-child(5) {
    background: black;
}
div:nth-child(6) {
    background: green;
}
div:nth-child(7) {
    background: yellow;
}
```

If you desire more than seven divs, it will be more practical with javascript like

```js
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

for(var i =0; i < divs.length; i++){
divs[i].style.background = getRandomColor();
}
function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}
```

```html
<div>test</div>
<div>test</div>
<div>test</div>
<div>test</div>
<div>test</div>
<div>test</div>
<div>test</div>
<div>test</div>
<div>test</div>
<div>test</div>
```

[Random color generator in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484506/random-color-generator-in-javascript)

Comment: @AnmarCSE thanks lets say should there be more than 7 divs, is there anyway I can increment the number in child() automatically in the external sheet

Comment: `getRandomColor` doesn't guarantee *unique* colors, although it would be rare for the same color to come up twice.  Very good answer, +1.

Comment: To prevent duplicate you can cache the already used colors inside an array. and check every time if the generated color is already used. And if it it's, generate another one.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in PHP itself as follows

Declare an array which contains the colour codes and use the array when you create the `<div>`s dynamically.See the below code as an example

```
<?php $color= array("#341014", "#BE6353", "#2F2E3B","#20222B","#BB644C","#F8834E","#E4B9AC"); 
$i=0;
while($event!=$nextEvent){
   echo"<div id='sportType' style='background-color:".$color[i].";'>";
   //some code
   echo'</div>';
   $i++;
}
?>
```

You can just specify any number of colours in the array and it will apply the colours accordingly even if a large number of `<div>` is created,ie for eg if you want 100 divs to be created, you can just add 100 or more than 100 colour codes in your array and these colours will be used in the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the function `rand` to generate new colors

```
while($event!=$nextEvent){
$r=rand(0, 255);
$g=rand(0, 255);
$b=rand(0, 255);
echo"<div id=\"sportType\" style=\"backgroung:rgb($r,$g,$b);\">";
//some code
echo "</div>"
}
```

`rand` function will creat a random number to the RGB color collection.