# unable to createRange()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to select a dynamically added timestamp - hit enter in the contentEditable element.

```js
$('#content').on('keypress', function(e) {
  if (e.which === 13) {
    console.log('enter pressed');
    e.preventDefault();
    var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    var element = document.createElement('p');
    element.setAttribute("id", "uniqueIdentifier");
    var date = new Date().getTime();
    date = date.toString();
    console.log('date: ' + date);
    element.textContent = date;
    //element.innerHTML = '<br>';
    range.insertNode(element);
    var range2 = document.createRange();
    console.log('$(#content).text(): ' + $('#content').text());
    var startOffset = $('#content').text().indexOf(date);
    console.log('startOffset: ' + startOffset);
    range2.setStart(document.getElementById('uniqueIdentifier'), startOffset);
    range2.setEnd(document.getElementById('uniqueIdentifier'), startOffset + date.length);
    //        $('#content p.new').focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id='content' contentEditable='true'>test</p>
```

I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught IndexSizeError: Failed to execute 'setStart' on 'Range': There is no child at offset 4.
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are two ways. Either pass the DOM node or pass node's text part.
If you pass the DOM node you should give the start and end offsets as 0 and 1 to create a range over the DOM node like this

```
range.setStart(document.getElementById('uniqueIdentifier'), 0);
range.setEnd(document.getElementById('uniqueIdentifier'), 1);
```

If you are giving the text node part then you have to give the length of the text node to create a range over the text part of the DOM node like this

```
var uid = document.getElementById('uniqueIdentifier');
range.setStart(uid.firstChild, 0); <-- firstChild refers to the text part of a DOM node
range.setEnd(uid.firstChild, uid.firstChild.length);
```

You are mixing the two ways. You can solve it like this

```
$('#content').on('keypress', function(e) {
  if (e.which === 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var date = new Date().getTime();
    date = date.toString();
    var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    var element = $('<p></p>')
                    .attr('class', 'uniqueIdentifier') 
                    .text(date);
    range.insertNode(element[0]); // the date node is added to the DIV at this stage
    var range2 = document.createRange();
    range2.setStart(element[0], 0); // <--- Give the entire date node starting at 0
    range2.setEnd(element[0], 1); // <--- Ending at 1 since there is only one node that you want a range of 
    var newNode = document.createElement("b"); // <--- I created a b element just so that the range is visible
    range2.surroundContents(newNode);
  }
});
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('#content').on('keypress', function(e) {
  if (e.which === 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var date = new Date().getTime();
    date = date.toString();
    var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    var element = $('<p></p>')
      .attr('class', 'uniqueIdentifier')
      .text(date);
    range.insertNode(element[0]);
    var range2 = document.createRange();
    range2.setStart(element[0], 0);
    range2.setEnd(element[0], 1);
    var newNode = document.createElement("b");
    newNode.style.color = getRandomColor(); // <-- Just so that range is visible
    range2.surroundContents(newNode);
  }
});

/* Courtesy: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1484514 */
function getRandomColor() {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id='content' contentEditable='true'>test</p>
```

Comment: great answer! Thanks, the .firstChild did it for me. Wasn't clear from the reference to me that we have to call .firstChild on a span element to define the text within.