# how to generate hexadecimal color code like this

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am generating unique background color for the contact list, like this

[image]

[image]

I am trying to generate this like this..

**Example**

```
     <ul id="_blocks"></ul>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                $("<li/>").addClass("bts")
                           .append($("<span/>").addClass("_pe_h")
                            .append($("<div/>").addClass("nonDraftPart _pe_o1 _pe_H1")
                           .append(i)))
                            .appendTo($("#_blocks"));
            }
            $('.nonDraftPart').each(function () {
                var hue = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor((256 - 199) * Math.random()) + 200) + ',' + (Math.floor((256 - 199) * Math.random()) + 200) + ',' + (Math.floor((256 - 199) * Math.random()) + 200) + ')';
                $(this).css({ "background-color": hue, "background-size": "cover", "background-position": "50% 50%" });
                console.log(hue);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

[Working Example Js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prasadraja07/wstf9j9c/)

Comment: Not certain what requirement is ?

Comment: What the the coding challenge?

Comment: No coding challenge here.... Need to generate a different set of color codes what i have attached in the image.. meanwhile did you check the working sample ?

Comment: Is requirement to generate pseudo random hexadecimal color codes ?

Comment: so what you actually unable to do ?

Comment: @Mayank kindly check my working example....i have tried to generate different hexadecimal color codes....but i could not achieve color codes like wat i have attached in the image

Comment: I hope you know that the rgb value indicates red, green and blue colors and the maximum value allowed is 255. If all are 255, it means white colors. After inspecting the generated values, all of the values are closer to 255 and hence you see lighter shades.

Comment: BTW, you still didn't mention whether seeing lighter shades is your issue.

Comment: @PrasadRaja Try using `for` loop , see post

Comment: Updated your fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/wstf9j9c/3/

Comment: @SherinMathew the color should be more attractive.. its seems like a dim...since i have attached the image..... i was expecting to get like that...

Comment: May be this post answered by @Adam Cole will help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484506/random-color-generator-in-javascript. He also refers to http://blog.adamcole.ca/2011/11/simple-javascript-rainbow-color.html.

Answer (score 0):

> Is requirement to generate pseudo random hexadecimal color codes ?

---

> yeah

---

```js
function randHex() {
  for (var r = "#"
         // valid hex characters
       , s = "0123456789abcdef"
       ; r.length < 7
       ; r += s.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * s.length))
  );
  return r
}

window.onclick = function() {
  console.log(randHex())
}
```