# Javascript generate random color with equivalent highlight

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, chart.js

I'm working with [charts.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) library and I need to generate random colors for the charts units.

I saw a lot of answers on how to do so. Like [Anatoliy answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1484514/665783) for example.

The thing is, I need it's equivalent highlight color as well (or any close color) to fulfill the 'highlight' field of the charts.js Pie.

```
{
    value: 300,
    color: "#30a5ff",
    highlight: "#62b9fb",
    label: "Label"
},
```

Comment: If you vote down, please supply an explanation at least. I think this is very common scenario when working with charts.js.

Comment: What is the relationship between the original color and the highlight color? Color complement? Just two randomly different colors? Same hue but darker/brighter? ...

Comment: As I wrote, any close color would be fine, The brighter would be perfect.

Comment: You've given me something to work with, I suppose, but what do you mean by "close"? Same hue but slightly different brightness? Same brightness but slightly different hue? Just vaguely somewhere close on the colour wheel? Something else?

Comment: work with HSL color values, i.e. `hsl(hue, saturation, light)` makes this sort of thing trivial - supported even in IE since IE9

Comment: @AndrewWillems A little bit brightness from the original color will be good.

Comment: @JaromandaX This is perfect. I didn't know about this possibility. Thank you !.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one among many possible solutions. Get a random hue between 0 and 360. Use 100% saturation and 50% lightness for the main color, and 100% saturation and, say, 80% lightness for the "highlight" color. Just keep clicking the "Run code snippet" button to see more random colors.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(d => {
  const hue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 360);
  d.style.backgroundColor = `hsl(${hue}, 100%, 50%)`;
  d.style.borderColor     = `hsl(${hue}, 100%, 80%)`;
});
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: solid 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```