# random color for every tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have this piece of javascript and I need every element "title" to be colored with different randomized color. I accomplished colorize only the first one. It is possible? Thanks

```
var randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
document.getElementById('title').style.color = randomColor;

<div id="title"><a>TEXT1</a></div>...<div id="title"><a>TEXT2</a></div>...
```

Comment: It is possible? - Yes. BTW, you cannot use duplicate IDs

Comment: **`#` missing** .add `'#'+randomColor` in a dom

Comment: `<div onload='this.style.color = Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);' ...>...`

Comment: Yeah just change id to class. Generate a 6 digit random number that is Hexa decimal number. Assigin the number as the color and add `#` before the number before assigning it as CSS property. Also clear would be to generate 3 numbers between 0-255 and assign as rgb values.

Comment: To you disappointment i found your question was already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484506/random-color-generator-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

As I already commented, you cannot use duplicate IDs, prefer using a `class` instead and modify your code accordingly.

```js
var getElm = document.getElementsByClassName('title');
for(var i = 0, l = getElm.length; i < l; i++) {
  var randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
  getElm[i].style.color = '#' + randomColor;
}
```

```html
<div class="title"><a>TEXT1</a></div>
<div class="title"><a>TEXT2</a></div>
```

Some explanation of how the above code works:
I am using `getElementsByClassName` which will return me an array of elements you want to target, in this case, it's the ones with the `class` name of `title`. Then I loop them, generate a new random hex, and assign it to the looped element.

Make sure you don't forget to concatenate your hexcode with `#`

Comment: nice answer. out of curiosity, how do you add the snippet code? do you have to remember the <--...--> tags that appear or is there a button somewhere to insert it? I looked for a button but didn't find it.

Comment: @Webeng Thank you. You can refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), it's called stack snippets.. you can include them in your answer by clicking on the file icon which has tiny `<>` in them.  Ping me if you still can't figure it out.

Comment: He said he wanted distinct colors for each title correct? You haven't adressed that

Comment: @SethMcClaine Did you check the result? I don't think you did

Comment: I'm assuming "different" === "distinct"

Comment: you're telling me that if he had 16777215 titles they would each have a different color?

Comment: @SethMcClaine I gave him the solution of why his both titles were not colorized, if he wants to keep a check for unique, he can modify it by checking if the random color already exist by pushing each on in an array and check using `indexOf()`

Answer (score 0):

Just invoke **changeColor();** functions.

```js
$(function(){
changeColor();
});

function changeColor() {
    var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
   
    for(var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++)
    {
        var innerText = paragraphs[i].innerText;
        var innerTextSplit = innerText.split("");
        paragraphs[i].innerText = ""
       
        for(var j = 0; j < innerTextSplit.length; j++) {
            var randomColor =getRandomColor();
 
            innerTextSplit[j] = '<span style="color: ' + randomColor + '">' + innerTextSplit[j] + '</span>';
            paragraphs[i].innerHTML += innerTextSplit[j];
        }
    }
}

function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>abcdefthuild</p>
<p>abcdefthuild</p>
<p>abcdefthuild</p>
<p>abcdefthuild</p>
<p>abcdefthuild</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this .*without classname*

1. using [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjXo8DEt7fTAhUCFZQKHZ9UBzsQFgg1MAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FAPI%2FDocument%2FquerySelectorAll&usg=AFQjCNGw4XxpSz-PKB1SUB1yNenuYzkpUw&sig2=SZVQ59z8HFASJOiUAfd4Tg).it will select the element.
2. Then applied each element with color using [`Array#forEach`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj83sXSt7fTAhWCEpQKHWEHBTgQFggiMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fjsref%2Fjsref_forEach.asp&usg=AFQjCNFrEEF2W3yTZqFaVdOonElRwwuGZg&sig2=Dn882KcSk-WeSXfx1_FztA)
3. And you are missing `#` in dom for adding color

```js
document.querySelectorAll("div[id='title']").forEach(function(a){
var randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
a.style.color ='#'+randomColor;
})
```

```html
<div id="title"><a>TEXT1</a></div>
<div id="title"><a>TEXT2</a></div>
<div id="title"><a>TEXT2</a></div>
<div id="title"><a>TEXT2</a></div>
<div id="title"><a>TEXT2</a></div>
<div id="title"><a>TEXT2</a></div>...
```

Answer (score -1):

**HTML**

```
<div class="title"><a>TEXT1</a></div>...
<div class="title"><a>TEXT2</a></div>...
```

**JS**

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('title');
var usedColors = {};
var getRandomColor = function() { 
    var randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
        while(usedColors[randomColor] === 1) {
      randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
    }
    usedColors[randomColor] = 1;
    return randomColor;
};

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++ ) {
    var randomColor = getRandomColor();
      elements[i].style.color = "#"+randomColor;
}
```

**JSFIDDLE**
https://jsfiddle.net/1cuwdLye/