# JavasScript infinitive background change with function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm curious if there is a way to repeat a function for as long as user stays on the page. I want function f1() to repeat changing the color of div #gallery. It's probably an infinitive loop or something, please help me.

```js
function f1() {
  setTimeout(
    function() {
      document.getElementById("gallery").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    }, 3000);
  setTimeout(
    function() {
      document.getElementById("gallery").style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }, 6000); 
}
```

```css
#gallery {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body onload="f1()">
  <div id="gallery">
   
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Check out `setInterval()` as it runs a function every X milliseconds until it's cleared --  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

Comment: Thank you so much, already found a solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can infinitely loop your javascript with **setInterval**:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#gallery {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="f1()">
  <div id="gallery">

  </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function f1(){
  setInterval(oneSecondFunction, 9000);
};
function oneSecondFunction() {
  setTimeout(
    function() {
      document.getElementById("gallery").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    }, 3000);
  setTimeout(
    function() {
      document.getElementById("gallery").style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }, 6000); 
}
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The previous method of using `setInterval` is really great, but I personally like to have a little bit more control over what happens so I use something like this for repetition:

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/foxfyjLg/)

The 'meat and bones' is a loop like this:

```
const target = document.getElementById('target');
const colors = ["red", "blue", "purple", "black", "gray", "aliceblue"];
const randomColor = () => {
    const randomInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length + 1);
    return colors[randomInt];
}
const userStillOnPage = true;

function f1(newInterval, continueWith) {
    target.style.background = randomColor();

    if (userStillOnPage) {
        setTimeout(continueWith || f1, newInterval || 1000);
    }
}


f1();
```

This method makes it easy to do all kinds of things like make the loop go faster by changing the interval or even injecting a different continuation function. It's quite powerful and easily abstracted to something very generic!

Comment: This method is far the most flexible and easily abstracted among the answers to this question. Really great.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);

function init() {
  var target = document.getElementById('gallery');
  setInterval(function() {
    target.style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();
  }, 1000) 

  // From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484506/random-color-generator-in-javascript
  function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
  }
}
```