# Compile scss before loading the page

Tags: sass

I have a function that returns a random color, so I need the color to change when the page reboots. But the color changes only when you save. What should I do?

Sorry for my English.

Comment: Can you show us some code? The function is defined in Sass?

Comment: `@function random-color() {
    $red: random(256)-1;
    $green: random(256)-1;
    $blue: random(256)-1;
    @return rgb($red, $green, $blue);
}`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend against compiling SCSS in each page load because it will affect you the performance of you web server and it may unnecessary complexity to your stack.

However, if you have only a few know elements, you can always use JavaScript: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1484514/439427