# How to give some div random background color?

Tags: jquery

I have several `div` in my page with class `.tg-item-inner` and now I want to give them each random background-color. there is my jquery code:

```js
var color = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
$(".tg-item-inner").css("background-color",color);
```

that will work. but all the div get one color. I want different color for each one

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484506/random-color-generator

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Random color generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484506/random-color-generator)

Comment: that will work. but all the div get one color. I want different color for each one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when setting the a color in hex you need to prepend it with a hash `#`

```js
var randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
$(".tg-item-inner").css('background-color', "#" + randomColor);
```

```css
.tg-item-inner {
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='tg-item-inner'></div>
```

Edit: each different colors

```js
$.each($(".tg-item-inner"), function(idx, elem) {
  var randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
  $(elem).css('background-color', "#" + randomColor);
});
```

```css
.tg-item-inner {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='tg-item-inner'></div>
<div class='tg-item-inner'></div>
<div class='tg-item-inner'></div>
<div class='tg-item-inner'></div>
```

Comment: that will work. but all the div get one color. I want different color for each one

Comment: Are you sure? still all are in one color