# Interval in JavaScript bookmarlet

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I am playing around with bookmark snippets and I am trying to make a loop that changes the background color rapidly. This is my code:

```js
var one;
funtion two() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
  setTimeout(two, 1);
}
void 0
```

I am not very good at coding, so I am trying to make it very simple.

Comment: Not sure what `void 0` is doing here, but as far as I know, it's not JS

Comment: @JeremyThille Before this question was edited, it was a bookmarklet with the `javascript:` prefix.

Comment: You call the `two()` function from inside itself, meaning it needs to be called in order to call itself. Funcception.

Comment: @JeremyThille (void 0) is valid javascript and evaluates to undefined.

Comment: You are really close https://jsfiddle.net/Lcceenbb/

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 perhaps the person who edited it should consider removing it if they are going to snippetize the code...

Comment: @lorefnon The more you know :)

Comment: changing background color every millisecond to a non hex value?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484506/random-color-generator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I submitted this snippet as an edit also, but I'm not entirely sure how those work. So I'm also submitting it as answer also. I've accomplished what you want by editing your original code as little as possible. Here's what I changed.

1. `function` was spelled `funtion`
2. You needed to use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`
3. You needed to then initiate that `setInterval` from outside the function `two()` you are calling it from: `setInterval(two, 1)
4. As others have mentioned, you can change the number `1` at the end to any other number of milliseconds you want it to hold each color for.

```js
var one;
function two() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
};
setInterval(two, 1);
```

Cheers!

Comment: Wow. "funtion"? I really messed up. :D Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to integrate the body's color change method into a setInterval function that will trigger at each desired interval.

```
window.setInterval(function(){
   document.body.style.background = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);

}, 1);
```

Ps :The interval is in millisecond

Comment: And why should this be better?

Comment: Better than what ? i think it's the easiest solution to do what OP wants

Comment: But you should definetly outline what you have changed and why thats better

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want with this code snippet:

```js
function randomBackground() {
  var red = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
  var green = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
  var blue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(' + red + ',' + green + ',' + blue + ')';
}
setInterval(randomBackground, 1);
```