# Split the div within the container using onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div with some random color at the background with width 100px. so i have another button which if clicked should split the div and give me two equal div's with random backgroundcolor. so if i click again 3 splits and so on. so on each click i am creating a new div within that 100px width. how can this be done in javascript?

Comment: Where is your code? Show us your attempted code.

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example? ([I downvoted because there is no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/))* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This becomes fairly simple if you utilise a flex container to control the element dimensions.

The random colour generator was created by ZPiDER ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5365036/746736))

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("btnAdd");
const container = document.getElementById("container");

btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    // Create a new div element
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    // Assign a random background color
    div.style.backgroundColor = "#"+((1<<24)*Math.random()|0).toString(16)
    // Append the new div to the parent element
    container.appendChild(div);
});
```

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100px;
}

#container div {
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  outline: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<button id="btnAdd">Add</button>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

quick solution: use a table and add a td with JS. Alternative you can use  and display:flex;. Here a guide: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```js
var colors = new Array ();
colors[0] = "yellow";
colors[1] = "blue";
colors[2] = "red";
colors[3] = "green";
colors[4] = "black";
colors[5] = "white"; 

document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.target.parentNode.innerHTML += '<td></td>';
  var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
  for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var a = Math.floor(5*Math.random());
    elements[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[a];
  }
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}
td {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Regards, Armin

Comment: this is exactly what i want but only with javascript and not jquery