# How to create a button that randomly changes a header's color?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create button that changes the color randomly of my HTML header. How can I do that using jQuery?

Comment: So what did you try? We are not here to code it for you.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to form a good question.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

E.g you could adapt this https://stackoverflow.com/a/1484514/3207478 on your button click event with JQuery or native JavaScript.

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Change color of header</button>

<script>
function getRandomColor() {
   var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
   var color = '#';
   for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
     color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
   }
return color;
}

function myFunction() {
    var myRandomColor = getRandomColor();
    document.getElementById("myHeaderElementId").style.backgroundColor = myRandomColor;
}
</script>
```

*next time google or use the search* ;)

Comment: to the haters https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16239 ;)