# OpenLayers automatically style line features

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-5

Is there any way to automatically style each feature read from a GeoJSON File and used as a source for a vectorlayer differently? I’ve attached a screenshot: This mess of green line features is more than confusing. It would be nice for each line to have a different color randomly assigned to it.
Thanks for your help!

[image]

### Edit: Added Code

Here you find the relevant Code I’m using for this representation. You can see that I define `green` as the color für LineStrings, but I’m wondering how I can automate the allocation of different colors to LineStrings.

```
// load GeoJSON with > 2000 Line Features
var fullGeoJSON = require("./data/datafile.json");
// Style function to be called in Layer definition, uses Styles defined in var styles
var styleFunction = function (feature) {
    return styles[feature.getGeometry().getType()];
};
// Define Style (one for all)
var styles = {
    "Point": new Style({
        image: image
    }),
    "LineString": new Style({
        stroke: new Stroke({
            color: "green",
            width: 3
        })
    }),
};
// Define Source
var geoSource = new VectorSource({
    features: new GeoJSON().readFeatures(fullGeoJSON, {
        featureProjection: "EPSG:3857"
    })
});
// Define Layer
var baseLayer = new VectorLayer({
    source: geoSource,
    style: styleFunction
});
// Define Map
const mainMap = new Map({
    target: "map-container",
    layers: [baseLayer],
    view: initialView
});
```

Comment: You should post the relevant code here. Otherwise it is not possible for the community to see where the problem is.

Comment: Hi @Carles, I added the relevant Code.

Comment: What I would do is to modify styleFunction so, instead of returning the fixed predeffined styles from the var "styles", it can check the data type. If the Type=="Point" it returns the default style, otherwise, it returns a custom generated style with a random color.
As a summary, when you load the file, every item is style using "style: styleFunction", so it calls to function "styleFunction" for every point, if I'm not wrong. This function reads the type and return the style from the array according to that type. What I propose is to have runtime generated data instead of using the array.

Comment: A style function is called repeatedly as the map is zoomed, panned, etc.  Returning a random color in each call of the function might result in undesirable changes.  I would suggest iterating once through the all features and setting a random color property in each which could be read in the style function `color: feature.get('color')` (similar to how feature names are used in text labels).

Comment: @Mike how would I get random colors?

Comment: You could set up an array of colors which would be suitable for your map e.g. `var colors = ['red','green','blue','yellow','cyan','magenta', ....  ];`
then use the js random function to select a random entry from your array `var randomColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];`

Comment: thanks! I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484506/random-color-generator – will look into using Hexcolors in OpenLayers.

Comment: For colors, check this out too: https://gka.github.io/chroma.js/

Comment: That’s nice @pavankguduru, I can image using the `chroma.scale` method for my purpose. I’m hoping to have time to work on this and then post an answer to my question based on the help I already got!

Comment: Sorry, but can anyone point me in the right direction: How do I iterate over all features? I read them like in `var geoSource = new VectorSource`…

Comment: `VectorSource.forEachFeature(function(feature) { randomColor = ????;  feature.set('color', randomColor)'; });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out thanks to all the help from your comments:

1. Load chroma.js into your project (I use npm and webpack and after installing it with npm I require chroma like this: `var chroma = require("chroma-js");`)
2. Define a randomize function:

   ```
   function randomize() {
       geoSource.forEachFeature(function (feature) {
           var scale = chroma.scale(["#731422", "#1CBD20", "#1CA1FF"]).mode("lch").colors(300); // Define color scale
           var randomColor = scale[Math.floor(Math.random() * scale.length)]; // select a random color from color scale
           var randomStyle = new Style({
               stroke: new Stroke({
                   color: randomColor,
                   width: 5
               })
           }); // define a style variable
           feature.setStyle(randomStyle); // set feature Style
       });
   }
   ```
3. call the function once and whenever the layer chnages: `randomize();`
4. "Define" Layer, this time *without* a style:

   ```
   var baseLayer = new VectorLayer({
       source: geoSource
   });
   ```

[image]