# Coloring the same elements in a string

Tags: javascript, string, colors

I work with JavaScript on my bachelor thesis.

I would like to read a string and mark the elements that are the same and follow each other in the same color.

I have not found a good approach yet.

I would be grateful for a good proposal.

This is what i have right now.

```
      function colorsetting(input){
        var collength = input.length;
        var now = '', last2 = '', colored = '';
        now = last2 = input[0];

        for(var i = 1; i <= collength, i++){
          if(now !== last2){
            colored = last2.fontcolor("green");
            last2 = now;
          }
          now = input[i];
        }
        colored = last2.fontcolor("red");

          return colored;
      }
```

Comment: Can you provide some examples of what your input and expected output would be?

Comment: I work with the rle algorithm.
input like: aaaasssssdddddd
output like:5a4s5d
But i what to show how rle works. so the input string should first be shown in color

Comment: Are you looking for certain patterns in your thesis? Or are you trying to go through all of the text and color anything that matches an input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split up your input string using a regex:

```
/(.)\1*/g
```

`(.)` grabs any character, and stores that in capture group 1.
`\1*` then tells the regex to match as many of those as it can.

Then, iterate over that array, wrap the strings in a span, each with their own colour.

```js
const str = "aaaabbbb123aaaaccccz";
const result = str.match(/(.)\1*/g);

console.log(result);

result.forEach(t => {
  // Create a span element
  const span = document.createElement("span");
  
  // Set the text in that span to be the current match
  span.innerText = t;

  // Set the span's color to something random.
  span.style.color = "#"+((1<<24)*Math.random()|0).toString(16);
  
  document.body.append(span);
})
```

(random color code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5365036/1835379))

Comment: @NickParsons: Derp, should've used `*`. Fixed now.