# How can I draw a 2d diamond with paper.js

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I want to draw a diamond using paper.js. The shape and colors of the diamond should change randomly everytime I re-run the function. How do i go about this task

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.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) demonstrating a possible implementation.

```
// Diamond random size settings
const MIN_RADIUS = 10;
const MAX_RADIUS = 50;

// Draw first diamond.
let diamond = drawDiamond(view.center);

// Display instructions.
new PointText({
    content: 'Click to draw a new diamond',
    point: view.center + [0, -80],
    justification: 'center'
});

// Draws a random diamond around the given point and returns it.
function drawDiamond(point) {
    // Get random radiuses.
    const verticalRadius = getRandomRadius();
    const horizontalRadius = getRandomRadius();
    // Calculate diamond points.
    const top = point + [0, -verticalRadius];
    const bottom = point + [0, verticalRadius];
    const left = point + [-horizontalRadius, 0];
    const right = point + [horizontalRadius, 0];
    // Build path.
    return new Path({
        segments: [top, right, bottom, left],
        fillColor: Color.random()
    });
}

function getRandomRadius() {
    return MIN_RADIUS + Math.random() * (MAX_RADIUS - MIN_RADIUS);
}

// On mouse down...
function onMouseDown() {
    // ...delete existing diamond...
    diamond.remove();
    // ...and draw a new one.
    diamond = drawDiamond(view.center);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var diamond = new Path.RegularPolygon(new Point(x,y), 4, 50);
diamond.fillColor = '#e9e9ff';
diamond.selected = true;
diamond.rotate(45);
```

x,y -> your coordinates

to generate random color have a look at this [Random color generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484506/random-color-generator)

as of your final code should look something like this

```
function diamonds(){
var diamond = new Path.RegularPolygon(new Point(x,y), 4, 50);
diamond.fillColor = getRandomColor();
diamond.selected = true;
diamond.rotate(45);
}
function getRandomColor() {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}
```