# Randomly assign cell background color based on unique cell texts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm looking for some conditional formatting solution where **a new cell background color is set to a unique cell text**. The image below shows this.

[image]

The tricky part is that I won't know any of the values within the list beforehand.

Comment: So if a new text is introduced in a cell - you want a new color for it, but if a text already exists in another cell, you want to assign to the new cell the same color? It is possible with Apps Script in combination with an `onEdit` trigger.

Comment: @ziganotschka You described it exactly - better than I did hah. Any other specific tips/recommendations on how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### How to assign a cell a unique color `onEdit`

- Apps Script [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) trigger run your function automatically each time a (manual!) edit was performed in your script
- You `onEdit` function should compare your new entry (the last row of a predefined column) against the already existing values in the column with [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)
- If the value already exists - use [getBackground()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getbackground) to retrieve the background color of the corresponding cell and assign it to the new cell with [setBackground(color)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundcolor)
- If the value does not exist yet:

  - use a function to [generate a random color](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1484514/11599789)
  - check with `indexOf` either this color is not contained in the already present background colors
  - [build a new conditional rule](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/conditional-format-rule-builder) assigning the new color to the new text
- If the value already exists - it will be automatically assigned the correct background color by the already present rules.

Sample:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.range.getColumn()==1){
    var text = e.value;
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
    var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),1);
    var values = range.getValues();
    var array = [];
    var row = e.range.getRow();
    for (var i =0; i <values.length; i++){
      if(row!=(i+1))
      {
        array.push(values[i][0]);
      }
    }
    if(array.indexOf(text)==-1){
      var backgrounds = range.getBackgrounds();
      var color = getRandomColor();
      while(backgrounds.indexOf(color)>-1){
        color = getRandomColor();
      }
      buildConditionalFormatting(text, color)
    }
  } 
}

function getRandomColor() {
  var letters = '0123456789abcdef';
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}


function buildConditionalFormatting(text, color){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var formattingRange = sheet.getRange("A:A");
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
  .whenTextEqualTo(text)
  .setBackground(color)
  .setRanges([formattingRange])
  .build();
  var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  rules.push(rule);
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);

}
```

Comment: Hi @ziganotschka. Thanks for the detailed explanation for the script! I'm trying to expand it to several columns but no luck so far.
I did the following changes to include column B as test:
`if(e.range.getColumn()==2)`
`var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),2);`
`var formattingRange = sheet.getRange("A:B");`
Why isn't working?

Comment: I found a way with these changes: `if(e.range.getColumn()==1 || e.range.getColumn()==2)`  `var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),2);` `var formattingRange = sheet.getRange("A:B");` . Thanks again. I'll try to figure out next how to make is accept any column.

Comment: Could you explain rapidly how to use this script I do not get it. I can save it in my *App Scripts* and it will take only column 1 if I understood. But seems to do nothing. Thanks