# How To Shorten a List of OR || Operators in an Google Apps Script

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-apps-script, operators

I'm trying to customize the following GAS script from [ziganotschka](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61009931/10789707) to add background colors to all columns of the sheet when the event (manually entering a value in a cell) is triggered.

I thought of using an array instead of the multiple || OR statements, but I'm not sure how to do it.

ziganotschka script (with my custom multiple || OR statements):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var c = e.range.getColumn();
  if(c == 1 || c == 2){
    var text = e.value;
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
    var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),2);
    var values = range.getValues();
    var array = [];
    var row = e.range.getRow();
    for (var i =0; i <values.length; i++){
      if(row!=(i+1))
      {
        array.push(values[i][0]);
      }
    }
    if(array.indexOf(text)==-1){
      var backgrounds = range.getBackgrounds();
      var color = getRandomColor();
      while(backgrounds.indexOf(color)>-1){
        color = getRandomColor();
      }
      buildConditionalFormatting(text, color)
    }
  } 
}

function getRandomColor() {
  var letters = '0123456789abcdef';
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}


function buildConditionalFormatting(text, color){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var formattingRange = sheet.getRange("A:B");
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
  .whenTextEqualTo(text)
  .setBackground(color)
  .setRanges([formattingRange])
  .build();
  var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  rules.push(rule);
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);

}
```

My request in short, how to get any index (the ???) from the `allColumns` array below to use as Column number in the if statement beneath?

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const allColumns = [1, 2];
  var c = e.range.getColumn();
  if(c == ??? ){
```

My goal would be to find a way to avoid having to use multiple || OR statements for each column (potentially an indefinite number of columns, depending on the trigger even involving entering text in any cell).

I've searched for a way to use an array in place of the || OR statements, and I've found so far the array.includes() method from this article [How to Easily Shorten Long Lists of OR(||) Operators in Your Code](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-easily-shorten-long-lists-of-or-operators-in-your-code-f095b9c06a28).

But my code doesn't work, here's what I've tried:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const allColumns = [1, 2];
  var c = e.range.getColumn();
  if(c == allColumns.includes(e)){
```

I've also considered [Getting a random value from a JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4550514/10789707), and [How to create an array containing 1...N](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24440995/10789707). But to not avail too.

My code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const allColumns = [1, 2];
  const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * allColumns.length);
  var c = e.range.getColumn();
  if(c == random ){
```

My code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const allColumns = _.range(1, 2);
  const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * allColumns.length);
  var c = e.range.getColumn();
  if(c == random ){
```

The [sample Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1crNR28UiMd3eUSGQvHYyjUPe_FPzFPAbec-tc-KBUSY/edit?usp=sharing) :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e` is the event object `{}` with [various properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)

`c` is the column number.

`if(c == allColumns.includes(e)){` is  incorrect. The script is asking to check whether `allColumns` includes  object `e`. That'll always return `false`. The correct syntax is:

```
if(allColumns.includes(c)){
```

Practice [Array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

Comment: it works great thank you! The one thing I did not try :). I'll try now to understand why it work and will be back later. Be well!

Comment: Ah. I think I understand now. My wrong `if(c == allColumns.includes(e)){ ` meant I was trying to know if the whole array was contained in the Column. But with your solution `if(allColumns.includes(c)){` it means rather the opposite: if the (whole) column is contained within the array (as a single element of the array, not the whole array)? The includes()'s parameter ('c' for this example) is the array index? It amounts to asking if the c column (any column) is an index of the array? The reference you shared helped a lot thanks! I had a hard time working with the GetColumn().

Comment: @Lod `e`  is a event object. It contains all the listed objects in [`debug_e` in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46860052/). `allColumns.includes(e)`  would be something like calling `allColumns.includes({range:{},value:''})`. `includes` has nothing to do with index. It just checks if any of the array's value is equal to the parameter passed. `c` would be number column, like 1. It's like calling ``[1,2].includes(1)``  Practice more you'll get it.

Comment: thanks that helps a lot! I'll practice arrays more next. Be well!