# How to make a website's dynamically appearing word, change color each time

Tags: javascript, html

I have some text on my website written in HTML:

```html
<h2 class="sub">Here is <span id="my_words">word1</span>.</h2>
```

I currently have JavaScript written that makes the word change dynamically on the site:

```
$(function () {
    count = 0;
    wordsArray = ["word1", "word2", "word3"];
    setInterval(function () {
        count++;
        $("#my_words").fadeOut(1000, function () {
            $(this).text(wordsArray[count % wordsArray.length]).fadeIn(1000);
        });
    }, 2000);
});
```

How can I make it so that the color of the word changes each time it cycles? Either from pre-defined colors or randomly.

Comment: `$(this).css('color', getRandomColor()).text(...).fadeIn(...)`? Just write `getRandomColor` like every other question regarding getting a random color we have on the site.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Random color generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484506/random-color-generator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the color of `span` using `$.css` jquery function as follows.

```js
$(function () {
    count = 0;
    wordsArray = ["word1", "word2", "word3"];
    
    const colorArray = [ '#FF0000', '#00FF00', '#0000FF' ];
    setInterval(function () {
        count++;
        $("#my_words").fadeOut(1000, function () {
            $(this).text(wordsArray[count % wordsArray.length]).fadeIn(1000);
            $(this).css('color', colorArray[count % colorArray.length]).fadeIn(1000);
        });
    }, 2000);
});
```

```html
<h2 class="sub">Here is <span id="my_words">word1</span>.</h2>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```