# I want to make radom rgb there, any ideas?

Tags: javascript, html, random, rgb

1. Hello I was making a javascript net art and I needed to make that
   rgb stroke random can anyone help me i'm kinda new in javascript.

   if(this.bbox.collision(Player.bbox)){
   strokeColor(255,0,0);
   }

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Random color generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484506/random-color-generator)

Comment: No it have to get that rgb values

Answer (score 1):

Use Math.random to get a random value from 0-255 for each of the three values.

```
let r = Math.floor(Math.random()*255);
let g = Math.floor(Math.random()*255);
let b = Math.floor(Math.random()*255);
```

Then you can call this by doing this:

`strokeColor(r, g, b);`

Comment: It works thank u!^^

Comment: Glad to hear it. If it works, you can check this answer so other people can find it if they run into a similar problem

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <div id="changer">Contents Here</div>
> <br>
> <button onclick="setRandomRgbColor()">Change Color</button>
> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
> ```

```
function getRandomRgbColor() {
   var color = 'rgb(';    
   color += Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + ',';
   color += Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + ',';
   color += Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + ')';
   return color;
}


function setRandomRgbColor() {
   //$("#changer").css("border", ' 2px solid '+ getRandomRgbColor());
   //or  
   document.getElementById("changer").style.border = "2px solid "+getRandomRgbColor();
}
```