# How to change color on each pseudo element on CSS Loop

Tags: html, css, angular, css-animations

so I was doing the typewritter animation effect on my web using only css that I found while googling, but I just wondering if I can set the color of each text to be different?

heres I attached my code on Codepen, you guys can check here

```
https://codepen.io/matadantelinga/pen/ExQeqjj
```

I just wondering if each `::after` that has text can have different color.

I use angular ionic as well to develop the project bytheway. Any advise would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it with css but I think that is good to do with the js.
Set a interval that every X milliseconds add a char in your string with a random color (or a color choosen randomly inside an array)

for randomize a color:
[Random color generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484506/random-color-generator)

Comment: any example for that??