# show multiColor Circles in google map

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, shapes

I have  HTML page and contain

**Header**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var citymap = {};

var cityCircle;

var myCenter  = new google.maps.LatLng(55,55);

function initialize()
{
    var mapProp =
        {
        center:myCenter,
        zoom:5,
        mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };

    var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
    var i = 0 ; 

    for (var city in citymap) {
        var populationOptions = {
          strokeColor: '#FF0000',
          strokeOpacity: 0.8,
          strokeWeight: 2,
          fillColor: '#FF0000',
          fillOpacity: 0.35,
          map: map,
          center: citymap[city].center,
          radius: 10000
        };
        // Add the circle for this city to the map.
        cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle(populationOptions);

        // show tweeeeetsssssssss /////// 
        google.maps.event.addListener(cityCircle, 'click', function() {                     
           //alert(text);
        });

        /*
        google.maps.event.addListener(cityCircle, 'click', function() {
            new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: 'hello!'}).open(map, cityCircle);
        });*/

      }
```

as we show ... I draw a google map and define a circle with properties .
In the part of body page ... I have array of java-script which contain the coordinates

**body**

```
<javascript>

Coordinates[i] = {
         center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude),
         };
</javasript>
```

now ... all circles will draw in same ( color . radios ... etc )... what I want is how can I change this properties of the circles like for example ( I want 3 circle red ... 4 blue ... ).thx :-)

Comment: Not sure what the problem is... set a different `fillColor` inside `populationOptions` for each circle, and it will have a different color. Did you try this and run into a problem?

Comment: the problem is that the propreties of circle is exist in initialize function ... that is why I can define many circle color ... know what I mean ?

Comment: Hrmmm, not really? Not sure what you mean... can you add a color to the `city` objects inside `citymap`? Then you can just do `fillColor: city.color` or something along those lines...

Comment: It would be helpful if you told us where the list of colors would be...

Comment: `citymap` is empty.  Your code won't draw any circles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the strokeColor to a random (or predefined) color...

Here's a random function I like (from [Best way to generate a random color in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152024/best-way-to-generate-a-random-color-in-javascript)):

`strokeColor: '#'+(0x1000000+(Math.random())*0xffffff).toString(16).substr(1,6)`

Edit:
As pointed out you'll probably want to generate the color first:

```
var color = '#'+(0x1000000+(Math.random())*0xffffff).toString(16).substr(1,6)`
```

And then set both

```
strokeColor: color,
fillColor: color
```

Re-edit:
So add the color to your array:

```
Coordinates[i] = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude),
    color: '#ff0000'
};
```

and use that

```
strokeColor: citymap[city].color,
fillColor: citymap[city].color
```

(I don't see the link from `Coordinates` to `citymap`, but I guess you have that handled)

Comment: I don't want random ... I want to determent It Not show like random :(

Comment: I'm new here and clearly misunderstood the question, what is best practice, delete the answer or leave it?

Comment: @Mikk3lRo
thx alot ... that is what I'm looking for ... can u tell another thing 
when I click on circle I want to alert the coordinates ... I wort function addListener but It show my the last coordinates when I click on Any circle

Comment: I think you are supposed to open a new question for that, but this may answer it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15208965/google-map-add-click-listener-to-each-polygon