# Draw and fill random colored circles onclick

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am using a canvas element on my web page, and need to be able to draw circles on mouse click with a different color each click. Here is the code I have, which works on some sites but not others. My question is what am I missing for this to work? I know that it only has one color currently in the code, but as it stands, I click all over the canvas and nothing happens.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("cirCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

function createImageOnCanvas(imageId) {
  canvas.style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("circles").style.overflowY = "hidden";
  var img = new Image(300, 300);
  img.src = document.getElementById(imageId).src;
  context.drawImage(img, (0), (0)); //onload....
}

function draw(e) {
  var pos = getMousePos(canvas, e);
  posx = pos.x;
  posy = pos.y;
  context.fillStyle = "#000000";
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(posx, posy, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  context.fill();
}

function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
    y: evt.clientY - rect.top
  };
}

window.draw = draw;
```

```html
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="clickCircle.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="circles"></div>
  <canvas id="cirCanvas" width="250" height="250" onclick="draw  (event)">
  </canvas>

</body>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is example of a random color generator function.
Also you should try add the click event listener in an [unobtrusive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) way.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("cirCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.addEventListener('click', draw, false);

function draw(e) {
  var pos = getMousePos(canvas, e);
  posx = pos.x;
  posy = pos.y;
  context.fillStyle = randomColor();
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(posx, posy, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  context.fill();
}

function randomColor() {
  var color = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    color.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 256));
  }
  return 'rgb(' + color.join(',') + ')';
}

function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
    y: evt.clientY - rect.top
  };
}
```

```css
#cirCanvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="circles">
  <canvas id="cirCanvas" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Something must be wrong in my browser. I see the code running fine here, but when I run it local, nothing.

Comment: I have temporarily listed the whole HTML in a separate post. Basically the document need to be created before any calls are invoked on it.

Comment: Well it works perfectly when I don't have the javascript in a separate file. Thanks!

Comment: Try to put this line  `<script src="clickCircle.js"></script>` after the `body` tag.

Comment: Still nothing. I'll keep it all in the html file if it means it works every time.

Comment: One last change. How do I make it so if any of the circles overlap, the new circle will overwrite the existing ones?

Comment: @user121168 I believe it is already that way (new circle on top of the old one). Do you mean to remove old circle when the new one has exactly the same center?

Comment: Hi MaxZoom. I mean for the old circle to be removed if any portion of it is overlapped by a new circle.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to change color - you can randomize the colors:

[Best way to generate a random color in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152024/best-way-to-generate-a-random-color-in-javascript)

or use an array of fixed colors

```
  colors = ["001100","AA0000","00BB00"];
```

using

```
  context.fillStyle = "#"+colors[Math.round(Math.random()*colors.length)];
```

Random version:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("cirCanvas"),
  context = canvas.getContext("2d");


function createImageOnCanvas(imageId) {
  canvas.style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("circles").style.overflowY = "hidden";
  var img = new Image(300, 300);
  img.src = document.getElementById(imageId).src;
  context.drawImage(img, (0), (0)); //onload....
}

function draw(e) {
  var pos = getMousePos(canvas, e);
  posx = pos.x;
  posy = pos.y;
  context.fillStyle = '#'+(0x1000000+(Math.random())*0xffffff).toString(16).substr(1,6)
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(posx, posy, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  context.fill();
}

function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
    y: evt.clientY - rect.top
  };
}

//window.draw = draw;
```

```html
<div id="circles"></div>
<canvas id="cirCanvas" width="250" height="250" onclick="draw(event)">
</canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement a function which is able to generate a random color.

just use sth. like this:

```
function getRandomColor() {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}
```

[JsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/0e1702rz/1/)

Comment: Any idea why it doesn't do anything when I try running it on my web browser? I see it work on JsFiddle, but nothing happens in my web browser running it locally.